# Google Storage - Low upload speed with gsutil

Tags: upload, google-cloud-platform

We are currently evaluating using Google Storage Nearline for backups. The servers in question are located within a Hetzner data center, on average 80-100Mbit/s upstream and 300-500Mbit/s downstream. We're using Googles `gsutil` for accessing the storage and its `rsync` command to synchronize our backup directories. While downloads are adequately fast, uploading files takes way too long: Maximum upload speed is about 8-11Mbit/s. This is only happening with `gsutil` and not really usable for a backup storage location.
I know large files should be uploaded using parallel composite uploads, however [Google recommends to *not* enable it for Nearline](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads).

Now, my question is, are these low upload speeds expected? Is there a way to optimize it? As it is, we generate more data than we can push to Google Storage, and will have to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of objects to synchronize you might want to use the [gsutil -m](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) option, to perform parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) synchronization: `gsutil -m rsync -d -r data gs://mybucket/data`

“BE CAREFUL WHEN USING -d OPTION!”.

Comment: Well, I have several encrypted and compressed archives of about ~50GB each.. but I'll test the multithreaded approach tomorrow.

Comment: ...and?  How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Give [`gcloud storage rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/rsync) a try. It replaces `gsutil` and delivers much greater [performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/new-gcloud-storage-cli-for-your-data-transfers?e=13802955) thanks to updated logic and parallel transfer optimizations.

For a managed solution you can also try the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/file-to-file) which does the scheduling, error checking, and delivers fast transfers.